# Prove that a connected graph with $n$ vertices is a tree iff it has $n-1$ edges.

Tags: graph-theory, trees

What are different ways of proving this theorem, using different definitions for a tree (e.g. maximally acyclic graph, minimally connected graph, there's a unique path between any two vertices, etc.)

Comment: which ways do you know?

Comment: If you recursively define a tree as a tree attached to any leaf of a tree, then the proof is straightforward.

Comment: If you define a tree as connected graph without cycles, you are done noting that a cycle has as many edges as nodes, and attaching any further node to the cycle requires also at least one edge

Comment: If you define a tree as a connected graph with n vertices and n-1 edges, you are done

Comment: If you define a tree as minimally connected graph, then you are done because n-2 edges can't connect n vertices

Comment: All of the above sketches only describe one direction of the proof, btw

Comment: Congratulations, you are the 9999 user to ask this question. Click [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1291495/if-g-is-a-connected-graph-with-n-vertices-and-n-1-edges-then-g-is-a-tr) to find one of many duplicates.